# What is the HQL equivalent of this SQL

Tags: nhibernate, hql

Trying to do a bit more complex query, and thought that HQL would be better for the job.  Using nHibernate.

```
SELECT * FROM [Group] g 
  INNER JOIN [User2Group] ug on g.Id = ug.GroupId
  INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.Id = ug.UserId
  INNER JOIN Activity a on g.ActivityId = a.Id
WHERE u.Id = ? AND a.Lineage LIKE '?%'
```

I guess I could also just use the SQL as well (?), but not sure really how to load up my objects that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on what your entities are and what the primary object you care about is.  You seem to be pulling them all instead of just one entity.  I am going to assume Group is the entity from this example

```
from MyApp.Entities.Group as g
join fetch g.Users as u
join fetch g.Activity as a
where u.Id = :userId and a.Lineage like '?%'
```

That should get you started.  But with out knowing your structure, I am taking a shot in the dark.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I'm trying to get a collection of groups.

Comment: I think you're pretty close, I'll give it a shot and get back with you.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Got me to where I needed to be.  What I ended up using: var groups = repository.SimpleQuery<Group>("from Group as g join fetch g.Users as u join fetch g.Activity as a where u.Id = ? and a.Lineage like ?", currentUser.Id, string.Format("{0}%", lineage));

Answer (score 0):

If you have many-to-many connection (User2Group table) you should start from it and make all the joins on this table. If you have correct mappings, the query below will work like a charm.

```
from User2Group as ug
join ug.User as u
join ug.Group as g
where u.Id = :userId and g.Activity.Lineage like '?%'
```

Comment: I have a [HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(Group), Table = "User2Group", ColumnKey = "UserId", ColumnRef = "GroupId")]
  public virtual IList<Group> Groups and similar from User to Group many to many.  I originally started with something like this but my end result needs to be a collection of groups.